# Is read data from the package slower than reading from a folder on your hard drive?

Tags: java, object, load

I have object which i want load to memory on start program.
My question is: 
It is better to insert objects into the (JAR) package or put the folder with the program?

What is faster way for reads object?

EDIT:

```
    public MapStandard loadFromFileMS(String nameOfFile) {

        MapStandard hm = null;
/*
        InputStream inputStreaminputStream
                = getClass().getClassLoader().
                getResourceAsStream("data/" + nameOfFile + ".data");
*/
        try {
             FileInputStream inputStreaminputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\"+nameOfFile+".data");
            try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(inputStreaminputStream)) {
                hm = (MapStandard) is.readObject();
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        return hm;

    }
```

Comment: Vote down why? For fun? Amazing.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by loading? Creating an instance/deserialization, ...?

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking Load a saved object from a file, i edited post.

Comment: Why not create this object instead of loading a serialized version of it from a file or resource?

Comment: @JB Nizet Because it is a huge map , which create produces takes 10 hours.

Comment: Just a side note: did you consider options to somehow "partition" your data? If you are really taking about single map that is so huge that it takes 10 hours to compute it ... you should seriously look into separating this information to more than one map for example. I think you should worry about the fact that you have one gigantic monster "blob" of information; instead of worrying if it should be read from file or from jar.

Comment: @EddyG creating map is preprocesing, i must read words from another file, split, cut and sort all map. There are many words. And map is created ony ONE times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In theory it is faster to read a file from directory as from JAR file**. JAR file is basically zip file with some metadata (MANIFEST.MF) so reading from JAR will include unzipping the content.

Comment: Thank you, clean answer.

Comment: CPU-cycles are _much_ cheaper than disk reads.  A compressed entry will require fewer reads as it is fewer bytes, so even with the added decompression overhead it will be faster than reading the whole uncompressed file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a clear answer. Of course, reading a compressed archive requires time to un-compress. But: CPU cycles are VERY cheap. The time it takes to read a smaller archive and extract its content might still be quicker than reading "much more" content directly from the file system. You can do A LOT of computations while waiting for your IO to come in.

On the other hand: do you really think that the loading of this file is a performance bottleneck?

There is an old saying that the root of all evil is premature optimization.
If you or your users complain about bad performance - only then you start analyzing your application; for example using a profiler. And then you can start to fix those performance problems that REALLY cause problems; not those that you "assume" to be problematic.

And finally: if were are talking abut such huge dimensions - then you SHOULD not ask for stackoverflow opinions, but start to measure exact times yourself! We can only assume - but you have all the data in front of you - you just have to collect it!

Answer (score 1):

A qualified guess would be that when the program *starts* the jar file entry will load a ***lot*** faster than the external file, but repeated usages will be much more alike.

The reason is that the limiting factor here on modern computers is "How fast can the bytes be retrieved from disk" and for jar-files the zip file is already being read by the JVM so many of the bytes needed are already loaded and does not have to be read again.  An external file needs a completely separate "open-read" dance with the operating system.  Later both will be in the disk read cache maintained by the operating system, so the difference is neglectible.

Considerations about cpu-usage is not really necessary.  A modern CPU can do a lot of uncompressing in the time needed to read extra data from disk.

Note that reading through the jar file makes it automatically write protected.  If you need to update the contents you need an external file.